# How can I use ui:define and ui:insert within the same ui:composition?

Tags: jsf

I have a `ui:composition` that sits within a template, and I want to repeat an element both in template and the composition itself.

Here's an example.

**template.xhtml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"
      xmlns:fn="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
       xmlns:pt="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/passthrough">

    <h:head>
        <title>JSF 2.0 Hello World</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css"/>            
    </h:head>

    <h:body>    
        <div class = "header">
            <div class = "mylogo"></div>              
            HEADER 
            <!-- I want this content logo to be defined within module.xhtml-->    
            <ui:insert name = "content-logo"></ui:insert>            
        </div>

        <div class = "content">
            <ui:insert name = "content"></ui:insert>
        </div>

        <div class ="footer"> 
            FOOTER
        </div>            
    </h:body>
</html>
```

**module.xhtml**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
                xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
                xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
                xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
                xmlns:o="http://omnifaces.org/ui"
                template="template.xhtml">


                 <!-- define the module content-logo here--> 
                 <ui:define name ="content-logo"> 
                    <div class ="another-logo"> foo</div>
                </ui:define>

                <ui:define name ="content">                

                    <-- we also want to display the content-logo here--> 
                    <ui:insert name = "content-logo"/> 
                    <div class = "foo">
                        My main content
                    </div>

                </ui:define>

</ui:composition>
```

The defined content-logo will display within the template header fine - but it doesn't display in the composition body. Is there a way I can make this work without resorting to copying the HTML?

Comment: Like so: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4792862/how-to-include-another-xhtml-in-xhtml-using-jsf-2-0-facelets

Answer (score 0):

You can use ui:include in your module.xhtml like this

```
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
                xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
                xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
                xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
                xmlns:o="http://omnifaces.org/ui"
                template="template.xhtml">


                <!-- define the module content-logo here--> 
                <ui:define name ="content-logo"> 
                    <ui:include src="logo.xhtml"/>
                </ui:define>

                <ui:define name ="content">                

                    <-- we also want to display the content-logo here--> 
                    <ui:include src="logo.xhtml"/> 
                    <div class = "foo">
                        My main content
                    </div>

                </ui:define>

</ui:composition>
```